# Update Core Data when back button clicked of NavigationView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui

User can delete some Core Data in NavigationLink. How to save it when back button clicked and return to NavigationView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the `onAppear` method of the previous `View` in the `NavigationalStack`.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    var body: some View {
        Text("")
            .onAppear {
                do {
                    try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                } catch {
                    // handle the Core Data error
                }
        }
    }
}
```